# Create/Schedule android notification in the future

Tags: java, android, push-notification

## Scheduling/creating future notifications.

So I've been away from Android development for quite some time and a lot has changed with things like android 8.0+ and all that.

Things and way that I used to do no longer work or are deprecated. This brings me to ask this question.

### How do I create/ schedule notifications for the future?

I used to use an alarmservice with a wakefulbroadcastreceiver and just schedule a pending intent for the future via a date/timepicker. Since things I used for this have been deprecated or changed since then, I wonder:

How do I actually do this now?

I have spent 2 afternoons searching for tutorials on how to schedule notifications for the future but all tutorials are from when I was able to use the "old ways" and a couple of them I recognize when learning this the first time.

I have seen discussions of notification channels and things about scheduling in workers?

Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction or provide links to how to build a notification scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

### for alarm manager..

```
Date date = new Date();

            Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal_now.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal_alarm.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            cal_now.setTime(date);
            cal_alarm.setTime(date);


cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, your_hour);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, your_minute);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (am_pmFormatOne.equals("AM")) {
                cal_alarm.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0); // 0 = AM
            } else {
                cal_alarm.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1); // 1 = PM
            }


if (cal_alarm.before(cal_now)) {
                    log.error("Today's time is passed, set alarm for tomorrow..");
                    cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);// Today's time is passed, set alarm for tomorrow..
                }


Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), randomAlarmId, intent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

### BroadCast Receiver..

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        assert v != null;
        v.vibrate(5000);
}
```